# Not recognizing my SSH key

Tags: 16.04, ssh, putty

I just created a Digital Ocean droplet running 16.04, and only authorized my iPad for SSH while making it (because I have poor foresight). Now I'm trying to use PuttyGen to create and authorize a key for my desktop, but it refuses to recognize. I've tried generating new keys, using other programs to generate keys, adding the keys by hand, adding them through Digital Ocean, changing the file permissions to rw-r--r-, but none of it works.

Comment: And your desktop is running what OS?

Comment: The desktop is running Windows 10, so I'm using Putty 0.69 as the SSH client.